# Calling a public function in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

i have a public function GetName()in an .ascx file:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
public string GetName()
{
     return name;
}

...

...

</script>
```

I have a file .aspx where im trying to call this GetName() function. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your user control is part of the aspx page, you could do something like UserControlID.GetName() from the page.

If it's not, maybe you should consider moving the function to a class that's shared among files in your project.